# Sharepoint 2010 -BreakRoleInheritance(false) does it have any performacne impact/issues

Tags: sharepoint-2010

IN SP 2010 , to assign item level security we need to break inheritance, 
for that we can use BreakRoleInheritance , This API takes 
true /false as arguments.
i know that passing True to this API has performace impact (i.e. if u have large amount permissions at parent level then then it will take some time to copy these permissions to this item)

but i read on a blog (http://www.sharepointbriefing.com/spcode/article.php/3816551/Solve-Item-Level-Permission-Performance-Problems-in-SharePoint.htm) where it says even if you use BreakRoleInheritance(false) it has performace issues.

Answer (score 0):

Item level permissions are going to be more expensive than if permissions are done at the list or web level.  The real question is if your user scenarios and the amount of data that you have will cause you to notice this extra expense.  The only way to know is through testing.